# Journal biographies: Presenting name, degree, university, etc

Tags: publications, writing-style

I'm required to include a biography at the end of a journal article written by myself, John Doe, and my supervisor, John Smith. I'm a BSc candidate in Information Systems Engineering at Piled Higher and Deeper, where my supervisor is Research Director. My supervisor is also a Lecturer at Another University. How should I present that information in the biography?

Comment: John Smith, B.Sc. Information System's Engineering, University, City, Country.

Comment: This question likely belongs on english.stackexchange.com

Comment: (2) or John Smith, Research Director and Lecturer at University

Comment: @user2768 I have already asked it there, and someone told me in the comments: "This question might be considered acceptable on the Academia SE site."

Comment: @user2768 The answer in your first comment does not state if this person is a student or a graduate.

Comment: Brief sentences like this one are customary at the end of papers, next to author pictures (for journals that use them). If you are referring to this usage, I suggest you to specify it in your question.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Yes exactly.

Comment: @user2768 Please do not put answers in comments.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I got the exact opposite complaint within recent days. Actually, a mod just deleted by answer and made it a comment.

Comment: @user2768 Please let me know which answer/comment it was, so that I can review it and discuss it in Meta if I don't find it appropriate. If it really was the same case as here, it looks uncontroversial to me that this should be an answer and not a comment.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/154953/22768

Comment: @user2768 Thanks! That case looks more borderline than this, to me. One could argue that the main content there is *such a company will surely be doomed*, which does not answer the question and is just a tangential remark. I would not have converted it to a comment, personally, but I see the logic more than in this case. Anyway, thanks for submitting it as an answer!

Comment: @catfour Take a look at my edit. Does it capture your question? (Edit if not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following answers the original question, not the edited question. I'll update if the OP confirms they're [satisfied with the edit](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/154986/journal-biographies-presenting-name-degree-university-etc/154993#comment413509_154986).**

Questions about the English language are [off-topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/154986/how-to-briefly-mention-your-name-study-degree-university-and-residence-place#comment413451_154986) here, but the question might be [on-topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/154986/how-to-briefly-mention-your-name-study-degree-university-and-residence-place#comment413479_154986) had the context been explained. E.g., in a journal article's biography, how should the authors' titles, affiliation, etc. appear.  In that context, for the examples given, I suggest:

```
John Doe, BSc candidate, Subject Name, University A.
```

(It's unclear from the question what the precise Subject Name is.)

```
John Smith, Research Director, University B, and Lecturer, University C.
```

Since the full addresses of Universities A-C presumably already appear elsewhere, e.g., as author affiliations, they can be omitted.

Alternatively,

```
John Doe, BSc candidate.
John Smith, Research Director and Lecturer.
```

Or

```
...
```

(Options are numerous.)

Comment: Thank you. What if I want to start with "John Smith
is ..."?

Comment: I don't see why you'd do that  in your context. But, answers are numerous, e.g., _John Smith is a Research Director and Lecturer at University B and C, respectively_, or _John Smith is a Research Director, University B, and Lecturer, University C_, or ...

Comment: And regardless of how it is written on the university's website, which subject name is more correct: "Information System Engineering" or "Information Systems Engineering"?

Comment: The only correct answer is the official name, anything else is false